# SONARQUBE: Change this code to not construct SQL queries directly from user-controlled data

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic, sonarqube, critical-section

I have a use case where dynamic sql query is cinstructed from a user input to the controller action method.

Even the TableName and ColumnName are inputs to the action. Query is constructed as below for Postgres database.

```
sqlQuery.Append("SELECT * From public."\"" + tableName + "\" WHERE \"" + attributeName + "\" = @attributeValue);
```

No issue with implementation. But, **SONARQUBE** raises critical below error.

**Change this code to not construct SQL queries directly from user-controlled data
**
Please suggest how I can solve it. All the compliant solutions are not solving the issue.

I tried all the compliant solutions.

1. Tried to pass TableName and ColumnName as parameters. Solved the issue, but query is failing while executing it.
2. Instead of concat, tried to use string interpolation as given as fix. But, no luck.

Comment: _"No issue with implementation. "_ - how are you so sure about that? How do you know `tableName` and `attributeName` won't contain unsafe values? The message is because Sonarqube has traced `tableName` and/or `attributeName`'s possible-values back to unsafe user-supplied input - but your post doesn't explain why you feel the warning is incorrect.

Comment: There's no way to avoid concatenation when inserting identifiers. It is only values that can use parameters. You should be validating such identifiers yourself to ensure that SQL injection cannot occur but it may be impossible to avoid that warning. I've never used SONARQUBE but it may offer an option to suppress the warning in that specific instance.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD link](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're potentially letting the user put whatever they want in your sql. Sonarqube is right to highlight the problem. There really is never a good reason to write code like this. Your query lets you retrieve an unkown number of rows from any table. You have no idea what columns are going to come back, so no way of doing anything with the returned rows, other than dumping them to screen. Use a database browser instead.